# How to zoom into micrometers?

Tags: interface, measurement

Well, I'm trying to make a really precise and functional 3d model, but it seems like I reached the zoom limit and the grid limit in the milimeters.

I'm considering just increase the size of everything to 1 meter or such, so I can actually make smaller measurements and then decrease to its intent size before exporting.

But I feel like I would just mess something up in the process or just forgetting it all together.

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set unit scale in the Properties Editor, Scene tab Units panel:

[image]

Keep in mind that you will need to adjust some other settings to more appropriate values for working with those sizes, for example viewport clipping planes:

[image]

Comment: I was just looking at docs for this, and there is a note on the page. This only influences the values displayed in the user interface and not how things behave internally. For example, physics simulations don’t take the unit scale into account.

Comment: I did not know that. Worth keeping in mind.